# Shared Preference getting null in adapter how to solve it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences

This is the view when i click switch rent then async task will run and im getting result an dthe recycle view not updating and it shows image button and recycle view null pointer exception here is my code
[Image here](http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/img.png)

```
public void rent_buy_selection(String type,String propertyID,String placeId,String buildingName,String bedRooms)
{
    Property_listing1 listing1  = new Property_listing1(type,propertyID,placeId,buildingName,bedRooms);
    listing1.execute();

}


public class Property_listing1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String PropertyID;
    String placeId;
    String property_type;
    String BuildingName;
    String BedRooms;
    String image1,SenderId;

    JSONArray detail;

    JSONParser ob = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jArray;
    Property_listing1(String type,String propertyID,String PlaceId,String buildingName,String bedRooms) {
        Log.e("listFragment",":"+type);
        PropertyID   = propertyID;
        placeId      = PlaceId;
        BuildingName = buildingName;
        BedRooms     = bedRooms;
        property_type= type;

      /*  if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            PropertyID = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("PropertyID");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            placeId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("placeId");
        }

        property_type     = type;//getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("property_type");

        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            BuildingName = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("BuildingName");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            BedRooms = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("BedRooms");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            SenderId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("SenderId");
        }*/

    }
    List<DataProperty> data=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("more_list", "1"));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PropertyID", PropertyID));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("property_type", property_type));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BuildingName", BuildingName));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BedRooms", BedRooms));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("placeId", placeId));

            try {

               /* if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("shared")) {

                    paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shared", "1"));
                    paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SenderId", SenderId));

                }*/
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = ob.makeHttpRequest("http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/property_listing.php", "POST", paramss);
            Log.d("Parameters",":"+paramss);
            // check logcat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {

                String success = json.getString("status");
                Log.d("test123",":"+success);
                if (success.equals("true")) {


                     jArray  = json.getJSONArray("result");

                    // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data     = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DataProperty fishData    = new DataProperty();
                        fishData.Title           = json_data.getString("title");
                        fishData.Id              = json_data.getString("id");
                        fishData.agentId         = json_data.getString("agent_id");
                        fishData.prprtyId        = json_data.getString("property_id");
                        fishData.Price           = json_data.getString("price");
                        fishData.Area            = json_data.getString("area");
                        fishData.agent_name      = json_data.getString("first_name");
                        fishData.agent_pic       = json_data.getString("fb_img");
                        fishData.Bedrooms        = json_data.getString("bedrooms");
                        fishData.Bathrooms       = json_data.getString("bathrooms");
                        fishData.Image           = json_data.getString("agent_logo");
                        fishData.Phone           = json_data.getString("phone");
                        fishData.property_Img    = json_data.getString("image1");
                        fishData.agent_logo      = json_data.getString("agent_logo");
                        fishData.company_name    = json_data.getString("company_name");


                                fishData.shared = "0";
                                fishData.description = "0";
                               // data.add(fishData);

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.e("agent_name",":"+fishData.agent_name);
                        data.add(fishData);

                    }


                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    // flag = true;
                    throw new InterruptedException("test");
                }
                // Simulate network access.
                //Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                return false;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        String Title="";
        try {


                mAdapter = new PropertyAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When click the  rent

```
 public PropertyAdapter(Context context, List<DataProperty> data){

    Log.e("shared",":test");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   context.getSharedPreferences("reg_id",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("id","");
    this.context=context;
   // inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.data=data;


    PropertyID        = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("PropertyID");
    placeId           = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("placeId");
    property_type     = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("property_type");
    BuildingName      = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("BuildingName");
    BedRooms          = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("BedRooms");
    SenderId          = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("SenderId");
}
```

How to fix this issue?

error Log
    06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:161)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at com.ksoft.propreka.Adapter.PropertyAdapter.(PropertyAdapter.java:82)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at com.ksoft.propreka.Fragment.Property_list$Property_listing1.onPostExecute(Property_list.java:562)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at com.ksoft.propreka.Fragment.Property_list$Property_listing1.onPostExecute(Property_list.java:300)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 21:30:06.719 9677-9677/com.ksoft.propreka W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post error logcat

Comment: Your user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("id",""); is getting null ? please paste the line where you put the value id in the shared preferences

Comment: You should store your keys in a final String

Comment: im getting value in other activity it shows null in adapter @Pavan@HUSTLE@fn5341

Comment: check what is the context value is it null?

Answer (score 0):

are you put id preference in shared preference like below before call adapter

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("reg_id",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("id","1323");
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: yes i added id in shared preference but still get null

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("reg_id",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Android verify if this sharedPreference with this "id" already exists, if not it creates one, if it is then get its value.

Before you get values from SharedPreferences you got to put informations on it using `Editor` like the sample bellow:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("reg_id", fieldText.getText().toString());
editor.apply();
```

I believe that's it what you're missing, your creating a SharedPref but you aren't putting the values on it.

Remembering that SharedPref only can store primitive values.